# Entity Framework & Unit Of Work Design issue with Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am facing a problem to save data using UnitOfWork. I mean I am unable to save data using **UnitOFWork.Commit()** from Controller class. My Implementation check bellow.

**IUnitOfWork**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<C> :  IDisposable
{
        int Commit();
        C GetContext { get; set; }
        TransactionScope BeginTransaction();
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
   public class UnitOfWork<C> : IUnitOfWork<C> where C : DbContext
    {
        private bool _disposed;
        private readonly C _dbContext = null;
        private TransactionScope _transaction;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            GetContext = _dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>();
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            return GetContext.SaveChanges();
        }


        public C GetContext
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public TransactionScope BeginTransaction()
        {
            if (null != _transaction)
            {
                _transaction = new TransactionScope();
            }

            return _transaction;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (null != _transaction)
                    {
                        _transaction.Dispose();
                    }

                    if (null != _dbContext)
                    {
                        _dbContext.Dispose();
                    }

                }

            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        #endregion


    }
```

Now within **RepositoryBase / GenericRepository**

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<C, E> : IRepository<E> where E : class where C : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IDbSet<E> _dbSet;

        protected RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork<C> unitOfWork)
        {
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;

            _dbSet = UnitOfWork.GetContext.Set<E>();

        }

        protected IUnitOfWork<C> UnitOfWork
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }


        #region IRepository<E> Members

        public void Insert(E entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
            UnitOfWork.GetContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            UnitOfWork.Commit();
        }

[...]
```

When I use **UnitOfWork.Commit();** within **GenericRepository** I am able to save data successfully. But When I use **UnitOfWork.Commit();** withing **Controller** I am unable to save data.

**Controller Code**

```
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepositoty, IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext> unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._employeeRepository = employeeRepositoty;
    }

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(EmployeeModel employeemodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                    using (UnitOfWork)
                    {
                        _employeeRepository.Insert(employeemodel);

                        UnitOfWork.Commit();  //OR UnitOfWork.GetContext.SaveChanges();                  

                    }  

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(employeemodel);
        }
```

If I use **UnitOfWork.commit()** within Controller then **GenericRepository** Insert method code check bellow

```
        public void Insert(E entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
            UnitOfWork.GetContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        }
```

As per my understanding this is a designing issue of UnitOfWork. Please help me to solve that.

**IEmployeeRepository**

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<EmployeeModel>
{

}

public class EmployeeRepository : RepositoryBase<MyDbContext, EmployeeModel>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository(IUnitOfWork<MyDbMContext> unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

**NinjetDIConfiguration**

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>();
kernel.Bind<ICountryRepository>().To<CountryRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserProfileRepository>().To<UserProfileRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();
```

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: Define "unable to save".  Does it throw an exception?  Does it do nothing?  Does it dance a little jig and give you the bird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Wrong DI (Ninject) Configuration create the problem. Solution check bellow.

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Actualy I don't use `.InRequestScope();` in my previous configuration. that's why It create mysterious behavior.

But Still unable to understand the reason behind that. Clarification welcome.

According the clarification of **Mystere Man** (**Problem:**  Since you use UnitOfWork both in your repository, and in your controller, you had two different instances, and each instance had its own context. So, you added the entities to one context (the one in your repository) but you called SaveChanges on a different context. Since that different context didn't have anything added to it, nothing happened.

**Suggestion:** you shouldn't need to make the repository InRequestScope, only the UnitOfWork, since that holds the context).

So the **Best solution** check bellow.

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();
```

Without using `_dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>();` , can it be possible to get DbContext instance via Ninject ?

Yes it is poositble According to **MystereMan** Suggestion. Check the solution bellow

**Ninject DI Configuration**

```
kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();
```

And within **UnitOfWork**

```
   public class UnitOfWork<C> : IUnitOfWork<C> where C : DbContext
    {
        private readonly C _dbcontext;

        public UnitOfWork(C dbcontext)
        {
            _dbcontext = dbcontext;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
           return _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public C GetContext
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbcontext;
            }

        }
[...]
```

Comment: InRequestScope() tells Ninject to pass the same instance of the object each time it's requested within a single Web Request.  Since you use UnitOfWork both in your repository, and in your controller, you had two different instances, and each instance had its own context.  So, you added the entities to one context (the one in your repository) but you called SaveChanges on a different context.  Since that different context didn't have anything added to it, nothing happened.  This is one reason I discourage the use of UnitOfWork, since EF implements UnitOfWork itself.

Comment: Usually implementing UoW on top of EF is redundant, unless you absolutely are sure you need to change your database technology in the future, and even then the benefits are dubious, since you will likely have to re-implement many queries.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to make the repository InRequestScope, only the UnitOfWork, since that holds the context.  From your other post, you suggested that you had already tried using InRequestScope, so I didn't suggest that.

Comment: UoW is not redundant for Entity Framework, quite often you want to get changes from several repositories to get written in the same transaction. Not possible unless you expose the EF db context or a UoW

Comment: @Mystere Man : Thanks for the clarification, **you suggested that you had already tried using InRequestScope, so I didn't suggest that.** . yes I did that but not in proper way, that a wrong implementation. **This is one reason I discourage the use of UnitOfWork** yes I agree on that, this also my personal feelings. **you shouldn't need to make the repository InRequestScope, only the UnitOfWork, since that holds the context** - I will follow that.

Comment: @Jaguffin : **EF db context or a UoW** this also possible to expose from GenericRepository<C,T>, Without implement explicit / redundant UoW, what you say ?

Comment: @jgauffin - Notice I said "usually".  99% of the time, people are not doing what you suggest.  But even so, you don't need a UoW for that, as you can create a transaction scope around multiple contexts (although this will most certainly promote to a distributed transaction).  You don't even have to expose the context, although it would typically require some kind of intermediate service layer.

Comment: @MystereMan: Can it be possible to get DbContext instance via Ninject ? without using `_dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>();`

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh - yes, you just bind your context to itself.  `kernel.Bind<myContext>().ToSelf();` then add it to your constructor arguments.  Make sure you also add `InRequestScope()` if you want the same instance in all objects that use it.

Comment: @MystereMan: You Mean `kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();`. But How to get that from UnitOfWork If I want to expose it from there ?

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh - You only need to make the context `InRequestScope()` as that is the thing that needs to be shared.

Comment: @MystereMan: I got that. But How to get that from UnitOfWork If I want to expose it from there ?

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh - I don't understand what you mean.  You just add the context to your constructor parameter arguments, and hold on to a copy of the context in your class.  When you return it, you return the copy in your class.

Comment: @MystereMan: Thanks, actually bit confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things you have left out of your question.  It looks like you may be using some kind of dependency injection, if that's the case, what DI framework are you using, and how are your bindings declared?

The real problem here is, I think, that your repository is being created with a different UnitOfWork than the one which you are using to call `Commit()`.  Looking at how the Controller is constructed and passed the instances will determine how to fix the problem.

By the way, TransactionScope is generally not required with EF, since it uses an implied transaction already.

Also, i'd be very careful about that using statement.  It can create a serious bug if you try to use the UnitOfWork outside that block.  Instead, I would let my DI framework take care of disposing the UnitOfWork, since it's the one that created it.

For that matter, I would also use the DI framework to create the context in your UoW instead of using Activator.

Comment: I use Ninject as DI Framework. Why do think it is a problem of DI? As a Said I am able to Save data , when I call UnitOfWork.Comit() within GenericRepository. But when I want to use within Controller then unable to save data using UnitOfWork.commit(), Using Di I use Kernrl.bind<IUnitOWork<MyDbContext>>.To<UnitOfWork>();. So do you feel forcefully create of  GetContext = _dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>(); is the problem ? Because I already declare Kernrl.bind !!!

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh - No, It's not a problem of DI, it's most likely a problem with how you are using and/or configuring your DI.  Your controller receives two objects in the constructor, which I assume (I have to assume, because you refuse to show us the code) that is being created by Ninject, which means it creates two different instances of UnitOfWork (the one passed into the controller and the one created in the repository).

Comment: Di Configuration

`kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>().InRequestScope();
//For Unit Of Work

Kernrl.bind<IUnitOWork<MyDbContext>>.To<UnitOfWork>();
Or

kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope();
Or

kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();` More explanation you may found here [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20481/entity-framework-unit-of-work-design-issue-with-repository-di-please-help]

Comment: `public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<EmployeeModel>
    {

    }

    public class EmployeeRepository : RepositoryBase<EauthorityContext, EmployeeModel>, IEmployeeRepository
    {
        public EmployeeRepository(IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext> unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        {

        }
    }`

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh - edit your post, don't post it in comments, it's impossible to read.